# Tensorflow- No module named 'object_detection.protos'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-slim

this is Geetha, i am a student doing Msc,i am trying to execute tensorflow object detection using google colab.I am trying to train the system,i am getting an error while executing train.py which is in research,My object_detection folder is in research folder

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/**init**.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 49, in 
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/content/my_drive/tut_kaggle/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 27, in 
    from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder
  File "/content/my_drive/tut_kaggle/models/research/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py", line 21, in 
    from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection.protos'

i have done the same thing in the gpu server,it works fine but when i tried with google colab i am getting the above error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `__init__.py` file in your research/object_detection/protos folder and in all other appropriate folders! The `__init__.py` file is empty but needs to exist for the protos module to be created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Install protobuf compiler and run the following command if you are on windows(respective command from different OS) from the correct tensorflow folder
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.